# WinFast TV2000 jak zainstalować w elementary

Tags: hardware

Dzień dobry
Mam lat 57, systemu Linux używam od jakiegoś czasu, zwykle jest to Ubuntu albo inna dystrybucja oparta na tym systemie.Ostatnio jednak zainstalowałem
E.OS i bardzo mi się spodobał ten system, w związku z tym moje pytanie:
Jak zainstalować kartę TV Leadtek WinFast TV2000 XP na ElementaryOS

pozdrawiam
Jakami

Comment: Please ask your question is English.

Answer (score 0):

Since elementary OS is based on Ubuntu, you may find the process listed on the Ubuntu Forum helpful. [HOWTO: Winfast TV2000 XP Series card on Ubuntu](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=647129). The steps are simple. First, you may need to uninstall the `tvtime` package, not sure. Then:

```
sudo rmmod bt878
sudo rmmod tuner
sudo rmmod bttv
sudo modprobe bttv card=34 tuner=43
sudo apt-get install tvtime
```

You might need to unmute a channel or two in `alsamixer`.